# C Program Store Routing Table

Tags: c, linux, routes

I need to know how to write a program that takes destination IP addresses, compares them against entries in the table and identifies the correct next hop address, from a routing table (storing the results in a physical file, e.g. txt).

Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Oblig: http://xkcd.com/138/

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Create link list and use structure for routing table entry

```
struct routeTable
{
    struct routeTable *next_Entry;
    int ipAddress;
    int interface;
};
```

somewhat like this you need to create structure and create link list.

Answer (score 0):

The routing table is maintained inside the kernel, as part of the TCP/IP stack. A userland C program just has no access to it.